# How to properly import using the CommonJS way

Tags: javascript, express, commonjs

I am confused on how to import a function in a file called *util.js* that simply reverses a string

```
function reverseString(str) {
    var reversed = " ";
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed += str[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
module.exports.reverseString = reverseString;
```

I want to access that in a different file, this one called *server.js*

This is what I have so far.

```
var util = require('./util');

util.reverseString();




var reversed = reverseString(req.body);
res.send(reversed);
} else {
res.status(400).end()
}
});
```

I am using postman to check the node modules, but when I run it I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I know the reverse code works, because I tested it earlier, so I assume my import is incorrect. But any help figuring this out would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reverseString` function is expecting an argument of type string(may be array also) and this same function you are iterating over the argument.

But while calling this function you are not passing any parameter, so `str` argument is setting to undefined.

`undefined` do not have any length property so it is thowing this error

Answer (score 1):

(My answer is targeted at ES5. There are some more shorthands in ES6, like default exports and named exports).

You can use a single export:

```
module.exports = reverseString;
```

Then:

```
var reverseString = require('./util');

reverseString("bobba");

//shorthand:
require('./util')("bobba");
```

Or return an object of named exports:

```
module.exports = { reverseString: reverseString };
```

Then:

```
var utils = require('./util');
utils.reverseString("bobba");

// shorthand:
require('./util').reverseString("bobba");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the library the function is in since you imported to a variable.

```
var util = require('./util');

// util.reverseString(); // this does nothing

var req = { body: 'some string' };
var reversed = util.reverseString(req.body); // ref util here
```